# Oracle Database REGEX_SUBSTR Query to get last number in string

Tags: regex, oracle

I need to make a REGEX_SUBSTR query to get the last two numbers of a SKU item number, I am really new to this as my boss is throwing me into a project I don't know much about at all. So forgive me for my ignorance.

Example SKUs:

```
AD-001250-12

AD-115QW0120-24

DGS1-55DF-6

DGS1-55DF-50
```

The SKU can look anything like the examples above, I need to use a regular expression substring query to get just the last two digits of each string. Thanks for helping as I am unfamiliar with the syntax and have no experience with this! :)

Comment: What is the output that you are looking for?  In particular, for your third sample row, doe you want "56"?  Or "06"?  Or something else?

Comment: I want the output to simply be '6' or '12' or '24' or '50'. Of course that number is coming from the last number in the SKU after that final '-'

Comment: OK.  So you don't want the last two numbers?  You want everything after the final - in the string?  What if the value was 'ABC-11543-123'?  Would you want 123?  Or 23?

Comment: For now, Justin, '23' is fine, but possibly in the future '123' would be useful

Comment: So then you want the last two digits after the final hyphen?  Getting everything after the final hyphen (123 in this example) would generally be an easier option (at least the code will be easier to read and understand).  What if you had 'ABC-11543-1A2B'?  Would you want "12" to be returned?

Comment: In our system, the only thing that will follow the last '-' are integers, so that isn't necessary, just have it return whatever is after the hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want everything after the final hyphen, you don't actually need a regular expression.  Just a simple `instr` and `substr`

```
with sku_table as (
  select 'AD-001250-12' sku from dual union all
  select 'AD-115QW0120-24' from dual union all
  select 'DGS1-55DF-6' from dual union all
  select 'DGS1-55DF-50' from dual union all
  select 'ABC-11543-123' from dual
 )
 select substr( sku,
                instr(sku,'-', -1) + 1, -- last hyphen
                length(sku) )
   from sku_table
```

`instr(sku,'-', -1)` returns the position of the last hyphen in the string.  Add one to get the next character.  Then your `substr` call gets everything after the last hyphen to the end of the string.  You could then get the last two characters from that if you want to get "23" rather than "123" for the last SKU but that's adding more complexity.

Here's an [example sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/5163) showing this query running